# how i can to show my report by linq that i create with Stimulsoft Report?

Tags: c#, report, stimulsoft

I'm using Stimulsoft for report in a C# Windows Form application.

This is my code:

```
private void btn_reportPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    stiReport1.Load("Report.mrt");
    stiReport1.RegData("DataSource1", db);
    stiReport1.Show();
}
```

When I click on Button "reportPrint" nothing happens and my program hangs.  I need to show my report with Linq2Sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query your data and pass it to the `RegData()` method, and not pass the `DataContext`.

Example :

```
private void btn_reportPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    var query = db.sometable.Where(x=> /*some condition*/true).ToList();
    // or var query = db.someStoredProcedure.ToList();

    stiReport1.Load("Report.mrt");
    stiReport1.RegData("DataSource1", query);
    stiReport1.Show();
}
```